# Stop figures/tables being inserted between the rows of a multipage longtable

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable, page-breaking

I have to include multipage tables in my appendix. I've been using the longtable package, but I've noticed that Latex inserts figures and/or tables in between the rows of a longtable, as shown in the attached image.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

```
\begin{longtable}{ccccc}
\caption[X]{Y}
\label{table:X}
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}
\caption[X]{Y}
\label{table:Y}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: An example of a table being inserted between rows of a longtable]

Comment: If your appendix consists almost entirely of floats, use [p] for all of them.  (Longtables are not floats.)

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example that reproduced the problem, but not allowing `[t]` position on that float or using `\supressfloats[t]` should stop that (I thought longtable supressed top floats but apparently not)